# If you save to become immune to a creature's trait/ability, are you immune to that trait/ability from all such creatures?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, immunities, fear, traits

So a Pit Fiend has a neat little thing called a fear aura. Essentially if you start in it, you have to make a save or be frightened. We know from [a related question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/140597/48793) that the [rules for combining effects](https://www.dndbeyond.com/marketplace/sourcebooks/dungeon-masters-guide#CombiningGameEffects) would require a creature subjected to this aura from two Pit Fiends would only roll one save. But the Fear Aura also says:

> If a creature's saving throw is successful, the creature is immune to the pit fiend's Fear Aura for the next 24 hours."

Does this mean a creature that successfully passes its saving throw would be immune to the aura from other pit friends, too?

Comment: I am closing as a dupe, because your 1st question is one. But you also included another one. If you concentrate on that, it might be reopened (though I am not sure whether we have that Q already or not tbh).

Comment: Hi user 60792! Based on Szega's comment, I've edited your question to pare it down to just the second (non-duplicate) half of the compound question. I thought it made sense to rephrase the title in a more general way (because other monsters besides Pit Fiends have similar save-to-gain-immunity type traits). If you feel that I've botched it, please roll it back and/or edit it to suit your style/aims!

Comment: Related: [How many horrifying visages can affect a PC?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/79204), and [How do multiple ghast stench fields work?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/138896)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### Only if the feature says you are immune to the effect from all creatures of that type.

The [Pit Fiend’s](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/pit-fiend) fear aura ability reads:

> If a creature's saving throw is successful, the creature is immune to **the** pit fiend's Fear Aura for the next 24 hours.

You would only be immune to **the** particular pit fiend’s ability. *An ability explicitly states if saving against it immunizes you against the same ability from all creatures of that type*. For example, the [Krasis’](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/category-1-krasis) hypnotic display ability says:

> A creature that succeeds on a saving throw against this effect becomes immune to the Hypnotic Display **of all krasis** for 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

If you fail a save from a [Pit Fiend's](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/pit-fiend) Fear Aura, you are [Frightened](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/appendix-a-conditions#Frightened)

**Yes**, you have to make a save against each individual creature that has the fear aura.

**No** being immune to one fear aura does not make you immune to the other fear auras.

However.. If you look at the description of [Frightened](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/appendix-a-conditions#Frightened), you will see that the effects do not stack.  If you have [Disadvantage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#AdvantageandDisadvantage), then you just have it.  It does not stack. But you would be unwilling to approach each  individual cteatute who's save you have failed.

> A frightened creature has disadvantage on ability checks and attack rolls while the source of its fear is within line of sight. The creature can't willingly move closer to the source of its fear.

**Note:** the combined spell effects does not apply here because the aura has a particular effect specific to each creature.  Which is that you can't willingly move closer to that individual.

Comment: Game feature's with the same name do not stack, so I do not think you can be frightened of more than one creature at the same time if those creature's are all using the same feature.

Comment: I think you're correct that you have to make a save against each aura, but I don't think they can both affect you at the same time, just the "most potent" one while their durations overlap.